# Angular Material cdkDropList: Prevent element from moving back when not dropped into container

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, angular-material

Default behavior on cdkDrag-elements in a cdkDropList seems to be that the element moves back to its origin container when dropped outside an accepting container.

The behaviour i'd like to implement is: The element stays at the cursor position where it was released until it gets dropped into a container (much like cdkDrag element without a droplist does).

Any hints on how to go about this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Im afraid not. I dove a little deeper into the workings of cdkDragDrop and it doesnt seem to be possible. I use a workaround now where i remove the the cdkDrag-functionality when the element is dropped outside a container, and add a custom dragFunction that allowes it to move it back into the droplist later. This is not very elegant and im hoping for cdkDrag to get a feature like descriped above in the future. Cheers!